# How do I get `pip freeze` to use my fork of a Flask module?

Tags: python, flask, pip, flask-bootstrap

Apparently there's a long-standing [bug](https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/pull/159) in [Flask-Bootstrap](https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap) that where `quick_form` omits the label for radio button fields. I found a [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705968/flask-wtform-radiofield-label-does-not-render) for it. First I applied the fix to my local pip installation of Flask-Bootstrap. Finding that worked, I forked the repository, applied to fix to my fork, executed pip to uninstall Flask-Bootstrap and install my fork.

But `pip freeze` lists `Flask-Bootstrap` and has nothing about my fork of it.

I need `requirements.txt` to use my fork instead of the original version. How can I do this? I know that I can [add a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source) in `requirements.txt` to indicate installation from a repository. But I'd rather avoid doing this manually every time I install a new Flask module.

Is there a way to automate the process of including the properly line in `requirements.txt`?

Comment: `pip install git+https://<your-flask-bootstrap-repository>#egg=Flask-Bootstrap` then `pip freeze` should list your repository for the `Flask-Bootstrap` module.

Comment: It doesn't. To double-check I uninstalled my version of `flask-bootstrap`, installed my version, ran `pip freeze` and this line was included: `Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.2.dev1`. If I manually edit `requirements.txt`, run `pip install -r requirements.txt` and then run `pip freeze`, it shows it at that point. Perhaps that will have to suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing these steps fixed the problem. First uninstall Flask-Bootstrap with `pip uninstall flask-bootstrap`. Then manually edit `requirements.txt` to include this line:

```
-e git+https://github.com/chivalry/flask-bootstrap.git
```

Finally, run `pip install -r requirements.txt` and `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. The last command will edit `requirements.txt` to include the commit ID and `#egg` name of the precise version used.

```
-e git+https://github.com/chivalry/flask-bootstrap.git@c28095521664dea05f2adbf5e01fe1a36392ab6e#egg=Flask_Bootstrap
```

Comment: It's called "editable install": `pip install -e path/to/SomeProject` (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/local-project-installs/#editable-installs)