# Trouble with Flask Requests - returns GET before any actions

Tags: jquery, python, json, flask, request

Right now, I'm working on a simple app that just displays back what the user typed in. I have a standard Flask layout like this:

```
/flaskTest
  main.py
  /static
    script.js
  /templates
    calculation.html
```

I'm working toward an app that will parse a user-created diagram into JSON, send that JSON to a python file to be processed into a plot, and send back an image of that plot that will appear on the web page. I have most of that work done but since I'm new to web development, I'm having a lot of trouble integrating the client-side and server-side components.

I'm trying to use jQuery and Flask to do this, but I keep getting back that calculation() is being called with GET instead of POST and I can't tell why. Here is my code:

#### main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def calculation():
    result = ''
    error = ''
    if request.method=='POST':
        result = request.data
    else:
        error= request.method
    return render_template('calculation.html', result=result, error=error)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

#### calculation.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/script.js"></script>
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Calculation</h1>
<form>
    <input id="userInput" value="">
</form>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
    {% if result %}
    <p>
        <label name='result'>Result: {{ result }}</label>
    </p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if error %}
    <p>
    <label name="error">{{ error }}</label>
    </p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

#### script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        userInput = $("#userInput").val();
        $.post("main.py",userInput);
    });
});
```

I know that for the simple task that I am accomplishing, it may be easier to do the whole thing as a form, but my end project will have no forms - just a canvas where users can create diagrams and a button to submit that diagram to be processed, so I would like to keep this implementation intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$.post("main.py",userInput);
```

to

```
$.post("/",userInput);
```

That parameter should be a URL not a file.

It should also be noted that this isn't going to update anything on the page. If you want to update something you are going to have to write some JS to handle the response from your Flask app. Additionally looking at the way your `calculation()` view is constructed I'm not sure AJAX is what you want to be using.

UPDATE: Since you want this to be asynchronous you're going to have to make a few changes:

**main.py**

```
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def calculation():
    if request.method=='POST':
        results = json.loads(request.data)
        # do stuff to result here
        # you will need to pass a dictionary back into jsonify()
        return jsonify(results)
    return render_template('calculation.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

You need to create a new dictionary to pass back into `jsonify()` so do whatever calculations you need to and create a new dictionary from it. My advice would be to create a separate function for this and save the result like so:

```
def some_calculation(a_dict):
    # MATH!
    return {'new_key': a_number}
```

And then in your view:

```
response = some_calculation(result)
return jsonify(response)
```

I eliminated excess code form your template:

**calculation.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calculation</h1>
        <input id="userInput" value="" name="userInput">
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        <ul id="results">
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JSON response will be appended to the new `<ul>`.

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        userInput = $("#userInput").val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/',
          data: JSON.stringify({input: userInput}),
          contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          success: function(response){
            // console.log(response);
            $("#results").append("<li>" + response.input + "</li>");
          },
        });
    });
});
```

I prefer using the long form `$.ajax()` method but feel free to use `post()`. Note in your application you will likely have to change `response.input` to `response.whatever_your_new_key_is`. I was just handing back the same JSON object in my example so I used the same key I  sent to the server. You can uncomment the `console.log()` line if you need to see what is in your `response` object should you make more changes to it. So if your new dictionary looks like `{"answer": 42}` you would change it to `response.answer`.

Comment: Changed the parameter but still getting GET. Also, shouldn't posting to that URL set 'result' equal to the data that they input, thus rendering the template to display 'Result: _something_' instead of the error message?

Comment: That's not what I'm getting, are you expecting the text `GET` to change when you click submit?

Comment: It may also be helpful to note that I am basing this preliminary app off of this post: [Web UI for Python Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668595/web-ui-for-python-function)

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that GET would change into whatever the user typed

Comment: There are some very important differences in that app and yours, the `<button>` element is inside the `<form>` tag. When there is a button in a form tag it's default behavior is to submit the form and reload the page. Also the form tag has a `method=POST` attribute.

Comment: Hmm, I was trying trying to take care of that using the jQuery code in the script so that POST would occur when the button was clicked, so maybe I need to add some code there to reload the page? I could also try wrapping the button in `<form>` tags but I don't want the input box to be part of that form since I won't have one in my final app.

Comment: That text isn't going to update since your AJAX call isn't making the page reload. I will update my answer to do what you have described

Comment: You need to be clear in what you want. Should the page reload when the button is clicked or not? If it reloads the changes will be fairly simple. If you want to do it with AJAX and not reload the page then you have to rewrite some of your javascript as well as your view.

Comment: I'd rather do it asynchronously, no reloading.

Comment: That worked really well, gave me a good base to build off of and I've been able to make a lot of progress toward how I'm planning to use it. Thank you!